# gradle build failed while building android app on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

Bonsoir guys,
I'm a real beginner into app developing but I was trying to create a simple mobile game just to start.
While trying to build it tho, I get this gradle error which seems impossible to figure out how to solve.

Here's the console log:

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Documenti\Università\Mobile Computing\SimpleQuiz\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 3
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but have you read the error message?

> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters.

I guess the 'à' in *Università* is the problem.

> Please move your project to a different directory.

You can move the project to a different directory where no non-ASCII char is in the path or rename that folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, really. I was so stupid because I thought the problem was about the apk destination folder path, not the project one, that's why I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot, really.